# HEX Comparison in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have table 'abc'(field : a, b, c)

```
a = unique id
b = start hex value, ex: AA3
c = end hex value, ex : FA8
```

What data type i must using for store b and c ?

How to select all and check(where) is 'BBB' are between a and c

the input is hex value.

what is the faster way ? compare int or hex in postgreSQL ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of postgresql are you targeting?

Answer (score 3):

Store the value as an integer type in PostgreSQL and convert between hexadecimal and decimal in the application or stored procedure.  This will result in better performance than using a `WHERE` clause with a function of a column, since in most cases indexes can't be used when checking the result of a function of a column.

Comment: Hi cdhowie, Thanks for your answer

so postgre can't compare hex value directly ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hex value" -- hexadecimal is a numeric representation, just like decimal.  They are both used to represent numbers.  You can convert a hexadecimal string to the corresponding integer value using, for example, `CAST(x'BBB' AS INT)`.

Comment: You can [index on the result of a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) in recent versions of PostgreSQL. But there's no need for that sort of thing in this case.

Comment: @Thessa, If you want to write hex numerals in your queries you write things like `x'BBB'::integer` or use `CAST` as cdhowie shows.  But keep in mind the difference between a number (the integer quantity stored in the database) and a numeral, which is just some representation.